# How to document an exception using Sphinx?

Tags: python, exception, python-sphinx

I can't seem to figure out how to document exceptions using Sphinx.

I've tried the following:

```
def some_funct():
    """
    :raises: ExceptionType: Some multi-line
        exception description.
    """


def some_funct():
    """
    :raises: ExceptionType, Some multi-line
        exception description.
    """


def some_funct():
    """
    :raises ExceptionType: Some multi-line
        exception description.
    """


def some_funct():
    """
    :raises:
        ExceptionType: Some multi-line
            exception description.
    """
```

Sphinx keeps saying:

> "Field list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent."

So how do I get rid of the message and what is the proper way to document possibly multiple exceptions with multiple-line documentation?

Comment: this question isn't really about documenting exceptions, no? should be edited?

Comment: There are **so many documentations** about it out there, like https://sphinx-rtd-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docstrings.html.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use a backslash for line continuation:

```
def some_funct():
    """
    :raises ExceptionType: Some multi-line \
        exception description.
    """
```

**Update:**

Indenting seems to work instead of escaping the newline:

```
def some_funct():
    """
    :raises ExceptionType: Some multi-line
        exception description.
    """
```

Comment: I've edited the syntax a bit, Sphinx seems to give the best results with that. I can't help feeling like the backslash is quite hackish.

Comment: It seems that the backslash isn't needed anymore. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @siebz0r: backslash is a tremendeous hack, and will be ugly with help (some_funct) for instance. It will not work nicely in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
def some_funct():
    """
    My documentation, but watch the empty line below (necessary)

        :raise: Exception

            when status != my_status 
            | status <= max_status
```

Note: https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#full-code-example has some nice samples (not on the multi-line exception unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

this give me somthing nice.

you forget the `:` Before the exception name

```
def some_funct():
    """
    :raise: 
        :IOException: a probleme occured
                      and it can't be passed
    """
```

Comment: Using this, Sphinx stops complaining about the indent and the output looks quite nice, but the exception name loses it's casing. e.g. `IOException` becomes `Ioexception`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a sample that wouldn't make Sphinx complain:

```
def some_funct():
    """
    :raises: ExceptionType: Some multi-line
        exception description.

    """
```

(note the blank line at the end)

Comment: Had a blank line at the end. Still complained.